# Build OpenSSL in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, build, openssl

How to build OpenSSL in Visual Studio 2013?
I try to compile in [this lesson](http://developer.covenanteyes.com/building-openssl-for-visual-studio/), but there is an error:
`Assembling: tmp32\x86_64cpuid.asm
tmp32\x86_64cpuid.asm(1) : error A2088:END directive required at end of file
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\`

I compiled under x64. What could be the problem? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6):

I wrote a note to [build OpenSSL here](http://www.tuan.nguoianphu.com/OpenSSL_compile_for_Linux_Solaris_Windows) (Unix and Windows).

Make sure you use the original OpenSSL source (do not re-use the compiled source code).

Open the Visual Studio x64 Win64 Command Prompt (2010) (in the Start menu)

```
%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" amd64

perl Configure VC-WIN64A --prefix=C:\openssl_x64 no-asm no-shared enable-tlsext enable-static-engine

ms\do_win64a

nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak

nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak install
```

Comment: I've just build OpenSSL 1.0.2f with VS2013 without any error. Please make sure you use the fresh OpenSSL source code, do not re-use.

Comment: ![I am use last version OpenSSL:](http://i.imgur.com/bEMoWgE.png).( OpenSSL 1.0.2g)

Comment: I don't undestand, what about you are talking

Comment: I mean I also built OpenSSL 1.0.2g (the latest version) with VS2013. It works well!

Comment: Thank you Tuan, your guide allowed me to finally get OpenSSL built when it seemed like nothing else was working.

Answer (score 2):

I remember encountering also the same error building OpenSSL 1.0.2d as a static library. A solution that worked for me is the following :

In a new command line window build OpenSSL and install it into C:\build\bin\openssl-1.0.2d-x64 directory:

```
cd C:\build\src\openssl-1.0.2d-x64
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\nasm
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64
perl Configure VC-WIN64A --prefix=C:\build\bin\openssl-1.0.2d-x64 enable-static-engine
ms\do_win64a
nmake /f ms\nt.mak
nmake /f ms\nt.mak test
nmake /f ms\nt.mak install
```

Resulting build is located in C:\build\bin\openssl-1.0.2d-x64 directory.

Hope that helps !

Comment: No, it did not help:

`Assembling: tmp32\x86_64cpuid.asm
tmp32\x86_64cpuid.asm(1) : error A2088:END directive required at end of file
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\
VC\BIN\amd64\ml64.EXE" : возвращенный код "0x1"
Stop.`

Comment: I think, by default, OpenSSL will compile builtin engines into the
separate shared librariesy. If you specify the "enable-static-engine"
option on the command line to Configure the shared library build
(ms\ntdll.mak) will compile the engines into libeay32.dll instead. so you may try without it !

Answer (score 1):

Take this answer updated for visual studio 2015

1 - Make sure to use the 1.0.2h openssl source.

2 - Make sure that you install (Old) nasm (NOT THE LATEST): use version 2.11 [1]:http://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/2.11/ from 2013 and put it on your path.

3 - Open any normal Command Prompt (cmd) - administrator is preferred - and execute these commands in the root directory of the downloaded source.

```
%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" amd64

perl Configure VC-WIN64A --prefix=C:\openssl_x64 no-asm no-shared enable-tlsext enable-static-engine

ms\do_win64a

nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak

nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak install
```

Answer (score 0):

Update for Visual Studio 2017:

1) I used the `1.0.2h openssl` source. I have not tried other versions.

2) Have perl installed and in your `PATH`.

3) Install [NASM](http://www.nasm.us/) and add it to your `PATH` (e.g. to C:\NASM and/or edit the `PATH` setup below). The latest version (`2.13.1`) worked fine for me.

4) Check and, if needed, edit the path to `vcvarsall.bat` used below.

5) (optional) Edit the install folder in the command bellow (set via `--prefix`).

6) Open Command Prompt in the root directory of the downloaded source, (edit and) execute the following commands:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\nasm

%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat"" amd64

perl Configure VC-WIN64A --prefix=C:\openssl_x64 no-asm no-shared enable-tlsext enable-static-engine

ms\do_win64a

nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak

nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak install
```

7) (Optional) In case you have multiple versions of VS installed, you might want to verify that the correct version of `nmake` was executed (`14.10.*` and not e.g. `14.0*` or `12.*`)